# starting a yesod web application

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to setup a test website with yesod.
I've installed everything as per the instructions, but I still get the error :

"the Application isn't built. we'll keep trying to refresh every second."

I've ran the commands : cabal-dev configure, cabal-dev build.

What can I do to be able to run my server and see the test application on the browser?

Comment: I start the web-server with `yesod devel --dev`  where `--dev` is needed due to the cabal-dev environment.

Comment: yes, it's the same command I'm using.

Comment: I would expect that you haven't initialized an appropriate database for the application to make contact with.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully start my application by using the command :

```bash
cabal-dev/bin/yesod-test Develoent --port 3000.
```

This wasn't mentionned anywhere in the docs.

Comment: As far as I know, you can set your configuration in `config/settings.yml`, so `yesod devel` knows which approot to use.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you should not build project yourself, just running `yesod devel` will build and run server in development mode.

The message you are getting in the browser, might be due to your application is still building, or contains an error, so check console for errors.